# Is there a way for codeIgniter to output html rather than xhtml?

Tags: php, html, xhtml, codeigniter

I'm just mucking around with codeIgniter, doing the video tutes etc. was wondering if you can specify markup output to follow strict html, I've noticed that helper form inputs etc. have a closing slash, that is contradictory to HTML 4 Strict.

Is it a case of just using xhtml for this framework because that's what it's mostly geared towards, or can I override it?

Tried searching documentation but can't really find anything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at '/system/helpers/form_helper.php', you can see the the closing slash is hard-coded into the return strings. You could extend the form helper by creating MY_form_helper.php in your application directory and modify this behavior.

See ["Extending" Helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html)

Comment: Ah ok, that seems like the thing to do then, shame there isn't a built in feature to easily swap output, thanks for the help!